# Understanding of write file operation in char driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning char drivers.But i didn't understand write operation of char device driver properly. the below is my write operation

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *fil,const char *buff,size_t len,loff_t *off)
{
    int count =0;
    int i =0;
    int flag=0;
    pr_info("user input string %s\n",buff);
    pr_info("user input string len %d\n",len);
    return len;
}
```

my doubt is if i write into my device like

```
echo "hello" > /dev/myDev
```

The below are contents of dmesg

```
[20596.975355] user input string hello
[20596.975355] 77b9e4
[20596.975355] insmod insmod
[20596.975355] n/zeitgeist-daemon
[20596.975355] atives
[20596.975355] 
[20596.975355] vars "${upargs[@]}"
[20596.975355]  cur cword words=();
[20596.975355]     local upargs=() upvars=() vcur vcword vprev vwords;
[20596.975355]     while getopts "c:i:n:p:w:" flag "$@"; do
[20596.975355]         case $flag in 
[20596.975355]             c)
[20596.975355]                 vcur=$OPTARG
[20596.975355]             ;;
[20596.975355]             i)
[20596.975355]                 vcword=$OPTARG
[20596.975355]             ;;
[20596.975355]             n)
[20596.975355]                 exclude=$OPTARG
[20596.975355]             ;;
[20596.975355]             p)
[20596.975355]                 vprev=$OPTARG
[20596.975355]             ;;
[20596.975355]             w)
[20596.975355]                 vwords=$OPTARG
[20596.975355]             ;;
[20596.975358] user input string len 6
[20596.975361] Device closed
```

so i didn't understand what is happening inside .Can any one please explain what is happening?
And how to access only user input string i.e "hello" 
 Thanks

Comment: When people who have no knowledge of a subject downvote questions, all you do is advertise your own ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

When you do a `echo` on the "/dev/myDev" file, this calls `write("/dev/myDev")` system call in the user space. This translates to a file_operations ops `(struct file_operations *)->write` call invokes the function `dev_write()` in the kernel space.

Now looks like the original definition may be wrong as its missing a `__user`, which points to the user space application buffer. Its not recommended to print or play around with the user space the buffer directly, as this is messing up something and printing lot of other data possibly some pages pertaining to `.text` section of some program.

Instead you should use create a kernel buffer and copy the contents using `copy_from_user()` or `simple_write_to_buffer()` before print the buffer into syslog. The reason for this kernel space pages are always pinned to the memory and don’t page-in page-out, while the user space pages are allowed to page-out/in of the memory, using the `copy_{from,to}_user()` and `{get,put}_user()` makes a pointer page are first validated to ensure page faults don’t occur while reading from these buffers.

ex: 
    static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *fil,const char **__user** *buff,size_t len,loff_t *off)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Like I mentioned the `dev_write()` definition you have put on the question in the issue is different from what is provided in the link. Likewise, in the link he is using a kernel buffer, copying the contents from the __user buffer before printing it. While in your code you are directly printing the _user buffer using a `pr_info` which is not recommended. Going forward I would recommended reading some basics of kernel module programming and device drivers before jumping into code.

Comment: thanks for your answer i followed this [link](https://appusajeev.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/writing-a-linux-character-device-driver/) it is working with out that __user and i added that __user still it is working as same .Please explain what is that syntax normally we use char variable-name there what is that __user

Comment: Sorry, I don’t get a part of your question about "syntax normally we use char variable-name". Do you see the diff between your code and the code in link for the `dev_write()` ? Not using `__user` should still give you a warning while building the module, but this would work as long as you are not directly printing the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` expects a zero-terminated string, but the buffer for `write()` contains only as many bytes as were actually written.

Furthermore, user-space buffers might be swapped out, or not exist because the program used a wrong pointer, so you must always use functions like `get_user()` or `copy_from_user()` to access user-space buffers.